# SQL command(s) to transform data

Tags: sql, db2

For the SQL language gurus...a challenge.  Hopefully not too hard.  If I have data that contains an asset identifier, followed by 200 data elements for that asset...what SQL snippet would transform that to a vertical format?

Current:

Column names:

```
Asset ID, Column Header 1, Column Header 2, ... Column Header "n"
```

Data Row:

```
abc123, 1234, 2345, 3456, ...
```

Desired:

```
Asset ID, Column Header 1, 1234
Asset ID, Column Header 2, 2345
Asset ID, Column Header 3, 3456
...
Asset ID, Column Header n, 9876
```

The SQL implementation that I am using (DashDB based on DB2 in Bluemix) does not support a "pivot" command.  And I would like the code snippet to work unchanged if column headers are changed, or additional columns are added to the "current" data format.  I.e. I would prefer not to hard code to a fixed list of columns.

What do you think?  Can it be done with an SQL code snippet?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I should have added some more context.  The folks on my dev team who have SQL skills have been stumped looking for a good way to do this in SQL without hard coding columns. They have concluded that we should write Node.js code to do it.  Before going down that path I thought I would reach out to the wider community for ideas.

Comment: Transformations like the one you describe are usually done in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: Neither the original data format nor the transformed format is destined to be presented to the UI.  There is subsequent analytics done on the transformed data, so it needs to end up in the database.  The candidates are SQL (if we can find the right SQL statements) or writing server side code, probably in JavaScript.

Comment: That sounds strange; a program (I'm assuming "analytics" is done programmatically) shouldn't really care if it reads rows or columns, as long as data are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by composing a pivoted table for each row and performing a cartesian product between the source table and the composed table:

```
SELECT assetId, colname, colvalue
  FROM yourtable T,
       TABLE(VALUES ('ColumnHeader1', T.ColumnHeader1),
                    ('ColumnHeader2', T.ColumnHeader2),
                    ('ColumnHeader3', T.ColumnHeader3),
                    ...
                    ('ColumnHeaderN', T.ColumnHeaderN)
            ) as pivot(colname, colvalue);
```

This will only require a single scan of *yourtable*, so it quite efficient.

Comment: OK, interesting.  From an SQL point of view this method is still "hardcoding" the column names (it appears).  But maybe a combination where we use a JavaScript program to generate the SQL statement as you have suggested...and then run the SQL statement.  Food for thought.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure, but you could also encapsulate the above logic in a view, eliminating the need to generate the SQL.  This kind of problem (requiring a pivot) is often indicative of a problem in the data model, so your best bet is to solve that problem first..

Comment: Thaanls Ian.  We are also looking at the data model.  There is of course a wider programming context that is beyond the scope of the question.  I wouldn't want to drag everyone into that.  Thanks again.  Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is `union all`:

```
select assetId, 'ColumnHeader1' as colname, ColumnHeader1 as value from t union all
select assetId, 'ColumnHeader2' as colname, ColumnHeader2 as value from t union all
. . .
```

There are other methods but this is usually the simplest to code.  It will require reading the table once for each column, which could be an issue.

Note:  You can construct such a query using a spreadsheet and formulas.  Or, even construct it using another SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will read up on "union all".  At first glance it looks like that means enumerating the columns which may become a maintenance issue.  But I will read up on it.  Thanks for responding.